# Find numbers with different absolute value in an array using java

Tags: java, arrays, loops, absolute

I am trying to write a program that prints out numbers with unique absolute value. 
Here is my attempt:

```
import java.util.*;
public class MyClass {

     static ArrayList<Integer> aCopy;

    public static void main(String[] args)

    {
        int myArray[]= {-5, 4,-6,8,-4,6,13};

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray));

        aCopy = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0; i<myArray.length; i++)
        { aCopy.add(myArray[i]); }

       System.out.println("Numbers with unique abs. value are:");
       findDifferentAbsoluteValues(myArray);
       System.out.println(aCopy);   
    }

     public static boolean findDifferentAbsoluteValues (int[] anArray)  
     {      
      for (int i=0; i<anArray.length;i++)
      {
        for(int j=i+1;j<anArray.length; j++)
        {
            if ( Math.abs(anArray[i]) == Math.abs(anArray[j]) ) 
            {
            aCopy.remove(anArray[i]);
            return false;
            }           
        }
      }
      return true;
     } 
}
```

but it gives incorrect output. I am not (yet) very fluent in java so it is not main concern for me than the solution is elegant, just need it working)) Anyone could shed some light what's wrong, please?

Comment: please include the actual output and the desired output in your question

Answer (score 2):

I understand the question you want to take a series of absolute values that are different. 
First wrong

```
aCopy.remove(anArray[i]);
```

It can not delete these, which has the same value. You find same value but `anArray[i]` not worth to be deleted. ex: i=1 anArray[1]= 4.  You will delete this

```
aCopy.remove(4);/* because anArray[1] = 4*/
```

Second wrong dont return false. Because loop not done.

I understand the question and answer in the following way;

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int myArray[]= {-5, 4,-6,8,-4,6,13};

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray));

    aCopy = new ArrayList<>();

   System.out.println("Numbers with unique abs. value are:");
   findDifferentAbsoluteValues(myArray);
   System.out.println(aCopy);     
}

public static void findDifferentAbsoluteValues (int[] anArray)  
{      
     for (int i=0; i<anArray.length;i++)
     {
         Boolean dif =true;
       for(int j=i+1;j<anArray.length; j++)
       {
           if ( Math.abs(anArray[i]) == Math.abs(anArray[j]) ) 
           {
               dif = false;
           }           
       }
       if(dif == true)
       aCopy.add(anArray[i]); //if you want absolute value aCopy.add(Math.abs(anArray[i])) 
     }
    }
```

Comment: Not bad, but you **really** should not keep the useless `boolean` as a return value and the `static` array. Just have the function return `void` and take the copy as argument.

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8+, you might use an [`IntStream.map(IntUnaryOperator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#map-java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator-) to get the absolute values, then a [`IntStream.distinct()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#distinct--) to get the unique values, and finally a [`IntStream.forEach(IntConsumer)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#forEach-java.util.function.IntConsumer-) to print it. Something like,

```
int[] myArray = { -5, 4, -6, 8, -4, 6, 13 };
IntStream.of(myArray).map(Math::abs).distinct().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Great answer to solve the problem (+1), but the OP is clearly struggling with the basics, so I don't think this will help him much...

Comment: This approach creates an  `IntPipeline` whose `distinct` method notes:  "While functional and quick to implement, this approach is not very efficient. An efficient version requires an int-specific map/set implementation."

Comment: @AustinD Thanks a lot for your remark! However, this is a note about the current implementation, using `distinct` on `IntStream`s should not be particularly inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

Your (main) problem is that your function `findDifferentAbsoluteValues` stops after it removed the first "duplicate" and you are removing without caution elements in a list you are iterating on. Here are a few pointers to help you improve your code:

- Do you need to keep the original array? If you don't, use an `ArrayList` directly for `myArray` and do not copy it
- Whether or not you need to keep that original array, your function should take your `ArrayList` as argument directly, not operate on a global (`static`) variable
- You don't need the result of your function, so `findDifferentAbsoluteValues` should return `void`

For the algorithm in your function `findDifferentAbsoluteValues`:

- It should not stop the first time it finds two integers with the same absolute value
- Try to see step by step by hand (or even better, with the help of a debugger) what your function does on your example to spot the problem(s)

**Edit:** Below is an example of a solution:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MyClass {
    // You don't need a global variable here
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      Integer[] myArray = {-5, 4, -6, 8,-4, 6, 13, 4, 4};
      // Copy the array using the constructor of ArrayList on a collection
      ArrayList<Integer> aCopy = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(myArray));

      System.out.println("Original array: " + Arrays.toString(myArray));
      findDifferentAbsoluteValues(aCopy);
      System.out.println("Numbers with unique abs. value are: " + aCopy);
    }

    // Takes an array as argument and works on it directly.
    // Returns void since no return value is necessary.
    public static void findDifferentAbsoluteValues (ArrayList<Integer> anArray)  
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < anArray.size(); i++)
          for (int j = i + 1; j < anArray.size(); j++)
              if (Math.abs(anArray.get(i)) == Math.abs(anArray.get(j)))
                  // Removes the second one and decrement to avoid forgetting any element
                  anArray.remove(j--);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In method `findDifferentAbsoluteValues` here `aCopy.remove(anArray[i]);` first you have to find the index of the element to remove,then remove it,otherwise it can give `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

```
if ( Math.abs(anArray[i]) == Math.abs(anArray[j]) ) 
{
     aCopy.remove(anArray[i]);
     return false;
}
```

**You are returning from function after a match is found which is not right,because you have to continue checking for other numbers also**.
So replace the `return` with a `break` statement.Also get rid of that `boolean` return type because it is useless,change it to `void`,as you are not using the returned value anywhere.

`public static void findDifferentAbsoluteValues (int[] anArray)`

Your code should look like:

```
public static void findDifferentAbsoluteValues (int[] anArray)  
 {      
      for (int i=0; i<anArray.length;i++)
      {
        for(int j=i+1;j<anArray.length; j++)
        {
            if ( Math.abs(anArray[i]) == Math.abs(anArray[j]) ) 
            {
            aCopy.remove(aCopy.indexOf(anArray[i]));
            break;
            }           
        }
      }
 }
```

It worked for me.

Comment: Is there a badge for "deleting your answer with negative score and comments and re-answer instead of editing"? ;-) Your answer still has the same problems as @JuniorDevelepor btw.

Answer (score 0):

You all are right. I messed up the inner loop, cause I had in mind a function I wrote some time ago that was checking if a number is prime, there it made sense to use return statement.
Big thanks to everyone who answered my post. Happy easter!